# What determines which server set-aduser connects to?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I was wondering this as I used it to create a user. `Get-ADuser` could see it straight after. Next I used `Get-ADDomainController` to presumably see what AD `Set-ADuser` created it on. However when I went to check that in the right AD's ADU&C console, user took the normal propagation time to appear. I can't find any way to have `Get-ADUser` specify the AD it communicates with, and if it is the server found via `Get-ADDomainController` why did ADU&C not show it?

Note: I am not looking to restrict `Get-ADUser` to a server in particular in the multiple AD environment, as a solution to this problem.

Comment: Typically you should specify the same server you are connected to for writing. And/or use the -Server parameters. In other code scenarios, .Net for example, an object DirectoryEntry maintains affinity with the specific DC across multiple operations.

Comment: @GregAskew Okay, so the server that `Set-ADUser` uses is the one that the login was against for the in context user, sans any explicit specification? Same with `Get-ADUser` I guess then? I wonder then why ADU&C didn't show it for a good 10 mins after. Closed and reopened. Tried manual refresh. Etc. No dice.